# Aggregation in pandas of consecutive values

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

I want to indicate whether the temperature dropped below 15°C in a data frame. How to do it more efficiently?

```
df['Was cold'] = df['Temperature']<15
df['Jacket needed'] = False
for i in range(len(df)-8):
    df.iloc[i].loc['Jacked needed'] = df.iloc[i:(i+8)]['Was cold'].any()
```

The data are ordered by time and each record represents an hour. `df['Was cold']` indicates whether the temperature was less than 15°C. `df['Jacket needed']` means that in the next 8 hours there was at least one when it was cold and I would need a jacket if I would have to go out.

Comment: It would be good to explain what your last 3 lines of code are doing. It's obvious it's more than just a simple boolean mask, so please explain what you're doing. Why i + 8?

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: Might help to provide sample input and desired output... Not quite following what "that in the next 8 hours there was at last one when it was cold" means in this case.

Comment: Just wondering if you're after something like `df['jacket'] = (df['Temperature'] < 15).replace({False: None}).ffill(limit=8)`....

Comment: I take it OP wants to check whether `df.Temperature` drops below 15 anywhere in a forward window of 8 time steps. so actually a bfill of limit 7 would work I guess? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the following work?

```
df['Jacket needed'] = df['Was cold'].rolling(window=8).sum().shift(-7) > 0
```